# Find the second duplicate word

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
File fis=new File("D:/Testcode/Test.txt");
BufferedReader br;
String input;
String var = null;
if(fis.isAbsolute())
{
br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fis.getAbsolutePath()));
while ((input=br.readLine())!=null) {
var=input;
}
}   
//String var="Duminy to Warner, OUT, Duminy gets a wicket again. He has been breaking...
if(var!=null)
{
String splitstr[]=var.split(",");
if(splitstr[0].contains("to"))
{
String ss=splitstr[0];
String a[]=ss.split("\\s+");
int value=splitstr[0].indexOf("to");
System.out.println("Subject:"+splitstr[0].substring(0,value));
System.out.println("Object:"+splitstr[0].substring(value+2));
System.out.println("Event:"+splitstr[1]);
int count=var.indexOf(splitstr[2]);
System.out.println("Narrated Information:"+var.substring(count));
}   
}
}
}
```

The above program shown the following output:
Subject:Duminy 
Object: Warner
Event: OUT
Narrated Information: Duminy gets a wicket again. He has been breaking....

my question is, the text may contain, For example: "Dumto to Warner, OUT, Duminy gets a wicket again. He has been breaking..." means, the above program wouldn't show output like above.. how to identity the text after the space for checking the condition

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if(splitstr[0].contains("to")
```

Change it to:

```
if(splitstr[0].contains(" to ")
```

It should then work fine IMO.